# LINQ to Files/Directory

Tags: c#, linq, file, directory

How to find a specific file in a specific directory with LINQ and return true if it exists?

Comment: Why do you need to do this with LINQ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var doesExist = new DirectoryInfo(folder).GetFiles(fileName, SearchOption.AllDirectories).Any();
```

Answer (score 11):

Why would you use LINQ for this? This does what you need:

```
string filePath = Path.Combine(directory, fileName);
return File.Exists(filePath);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like this:

```
var fileExists = new DirectoryInfo("directoryPath").GetFiles("filename.ext").Any();
```

But you could just use this if you already know the path of the file:

```
var fileExists = File.Exists("filePath");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also consider [FluentPath](http://fluentpath.codeplex.com/) if you like such a thing. It is a Fluent wrapper around System.IO I saw a while back. Here is a sample from the site:

```
Path.Get(args.Length != 0 ? args[0] : ".")
    .Files(
        p => new[] {
            ".avi", ".m4v", ".wmv",
            ".mp4", ".dvr-ms", ".mpg", ".mkv"
        }.Contains(p.Extension))
    .CreateDirectories(
        p => p.Parent()
              .Combine(p.FileNameWithoutExtension))
    .End()
    .Move(
        p => p.Parent()
              .Combine(p.FileNameWithoutExtension)
              .Combine(p.FileName));
```

Comment: I gave this a +1 for what I hope was the tongue-in-cheek nature of it, while appearing also to contain correct information!